# Why is New Registration disabled under Enterprise Application in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Thanks to the post that discusses the [differences between App Registrations and Enterprise Applications](https://medium.com/r/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F54071385%2Fdifference-between-enterprise-application-and-app-registration-in-azure), I understand the difference between these two concepts now.

Here's the situation I'm dealing with at work -
I am able to create 'New registration' under App Registrations blade, however, when I go to the Enterprise Applications blade, the 'New Application' button is disabled for me. Azure AD indicates I have the 'User' role. What role/permissions should one have in order to be able to 'Add Application' in the Enterprise Applications blade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, normal user roles cannot register **Enterprise applications**. You need to have an administrator role.

You need to have one of the following roles: **Global Administrator**, **Cloud Application Administrator**, **Application Administrator**, or **owner of the service principal**.

please  see: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal#prerequisites).

[image]

Comment: Users roles other than Administrator can register application in Azure AD if the "App registration" setting is set to Yes - which is [turned on by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-how-applications-are-added#who-has-permission-to-add-applications-to-my-azure-ad-instance). More detailed information is available in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#permissions-required-for-registering-an-app).

Comment: @MattStannett   Enterprise applications and app registration are different. Even if you set the "Application Registration" setting to "Yes", ordinary user roles cannot register enterprise applications. You need to have the role of administrator, please check!

Comment: @CarlZhou, my mistake!